# While loop inside a for loop to calculate geospatial distance between 2 datasets in R

Tags: r, gis, r-sf, geosphere

I have a `data.table`  with 957 geocodes. I want to match it with another dataset with 317 geocodes. The matching condition is geospatial proximity. I want to match each observation from the first dataset to an observation from the second one such that the distance between both observations is 5000 meters or less.

My data looks like this:

```
> muni[1:3]
         mun Lat_Decimal Lon_Decimal
1:      1001    21.76672   -102.2818
2:      1002    22.16597   -102.0657
3:      1003    21.86138   -102.7248
> stations[1:3]
   station_number station_lat station_long
1:          10003      25.100     -106.567
2:          10018      24.944     -106.259
3:          10031      24.523     -105.952
```

I am using the `distm` function from `library(geosphere)` to calculate the distance.

I figured the way to attack this problem is a `while` loop. The idea is to take the first observation from `muni` and measure the distance to the first observation in `stations`. If the distance is 5000 meters or less, then assign the `station_number` of the first observation in `station` to the first observation in `muni`. If the distance is greater than 5000, then try the next observation in `muni` until the distance is 5000 meters or less.

Essentially, it's a loop that finds the first observation in `stations` that's 5000 meters or closer to an observation in `muni`.

This is a preliminary attempt at it:

```
for (i in 1:957) {
  j = 1
  while (distm(muni[i, .(Lon_Decimal, Lat_Decimal)],
               stations[j, .(station_long, station_lat)]) > 5000 & j <= 317) {
    muni[i, station_number := as.integer(stations[j, station_number])]
    muni[i, distance := distm(muni[i, .(Lon_Decimal, Lat_Decimal)],
                                   stations[j, .(station_long, station_lat)])]
    j = j + 1
}
}
```

I can tell this is not working because none of the rows in ´muni´ appear to have been overwritten after running this loop `for (i in 1:3)`. I suppose there is an error in my loop that is ignoring the `station_number :=` and `distance :=` parts.

I would expect this loop to overwrite `muni` such that all the entire column had a `station_number`.

Comment: Would you be satisfied if you could match each `muni` observation to its closest `station` rather than the first observation from the `station` dataset under 5000 metres?

Comment: Are you able to provide a data set we can work with?

Comment: @FonsMA I thought it would be more efficient to run it with <= 5000 meters, but yes, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've read your few sample points as `data.frames` and converted them to  `sf` below for the answer. If you're attached to `geosphere`, forgive the pun, everything should still apply the same, given that `geosphere::distm` also returns a matrix of distances.

First we get your data into `sf` format:

```r
library(sf)

stations_raw <- "station_number station_lat station_long
1:          10003      25.100     -106.567
2:          10018      24.944     -106.259
3:          10031      24.523     -105.952"


mun_raw <- "mun Lat_Decimal Lon_Decimal
1:      1001    21.76672   -102.2818
2:      1002    22.16597   -102.0657
3:      1003    21.86138   -102.7248"

mun_df <- read.table(text = mun_raw)

stations_df <- read.table(text = stations_raw)

mun_sf <- st_as_sf(mun_df, coords = c("Lon_Decimal", "Lat_Decimal"), crs = 4326)
stations_sf <-  st_as_sf(stations_df, 
                          coords = c("station_long", "station_lat"), crs = 4326)
```

Then, we find the minimum for each interaction between dots:

```r
closest <- list()

for(i in seq_len(nrow(mun_sf))){
  closest[[i]] <- stations_sf[which.min(
    st_distance(stations_sf, mun_sf[i,])),]
}
```

Finally, we extract the identifiers and attach them to the original df, removing the mun_id as you request:

```r
mun_sf$closest_station <- purrr::map_chr(closest, "station_number")

mun_sf <- mun_sf[, c("closest_station", "geometry")]

mun_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 1 field
#> geometry type:  POINT
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -102.7248 ymin: 21.76672 xmax: -102.0657 ymax: 22.16597
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#>    closest_station                   geometry
#> 1:           10031 POINT (-102.2818 21.76672)
#> 2:           10031 POINT (-102.0657 22.16597)
#> 3:           10031 POINT (-102.7248 21.86138)
```

The plot below helps visually check that, in this toy example, we've got the right answer.

```r
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = mun_sf, colour = "red") +
  geom_sf_text(data = mun_sf, aes(label = mun), nudge_x = 0.25) +
  geom_sf(data = stations_sf, colour = "blue") +
  geom_sf_text(data = stations_sf, aes(label = station_number), nudge_x = -0.25)
#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may
#> not give correct results for longitude/latitude data

#> Warning in st_point_on_surface.sfc(sf::st_zm(x)): st_point_on_surface may
#> not give correct results for longitude/latitude data
```

[image]